# How to select data in 2 different table with ACCESS

Tags: sql, ms-access

Im trying to `SELECT` Data from 2 Different Table.

Below are the 2 Table

```
Table1
Date       Name   Value1 Value2
25/10/2021 Name1  1      7
25/10/2021 Name2  3      8
25/10/2021 Name3  5      9
25/10/2021 Name1  1      3

Table2
Date       Name    Class
25/10/2021 Name1   A
25/10/2021 Name2   B
25/10/2021 Name3   A
```

The wanted output is :

```
Name   Value1 Value2  Class
Name1  2      10      A
Name2  3      8       B
Name3  5      9       A
```

I tried the following query but It throw an error

> Your query does not include the specified expression 'Class' as part of an aggregate function

```
SELECT Table2.Class, Sum(Table1.Value1), Sum(Table1.Value2)
FROM Table1
INNER JOIN Table2 ON Table1.Name = Table2.Name
WHERE Table1.Date = #25/10/2021#
ORDER BY Table1.Name
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You miss to *group by* `Class`:

```sql
SELECT Table2.Class, Sum(Table1.Value1), Sum(Table1.Value2)
FROM Table1
INNER JOIN Table2 ON Table1.Name = Table2.Name
WHERE Table1.Date = #25/10/2021#
GROUP BY Table2.Class
ORDER BY Table1.Name
```